# Unable to update counter value in Jquerymobile list

Tags: javascript, list, jquery-mobile, counter

I have a element that I am trying to update on each creation of an item.

At the moment, a list is populated via a REST API, and I have a script that takes some info from each item, counts another table, and the answer is to populate the counter bubble of the jquerymobile list.

I have searched, and I understand I need to access 'ui-li-count' but I am unable to get to it. I have searched on here and tried many ways, but none actually give me the answer.

Using google console, this is how the element is drawn:

[image: element drawn]

This is how it should look

[image: the view]

This is the code I am trying, and failing badly :

```
console.log('get count : '+$('li[name=mobilelistitem_9]').find("ui-li-count ui-body-b").text());
```

I need to set the value, but here I am trying to find it, so I know what syntax to use to set the value.

I need this to fire, each time a new item is added to the list collection.  Using $(this) or Appery(this) is not working.

Any suggestions on this would hugely welcomed :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your selector for the count text seems about right; working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/z2zJL/, I guess we would need to see more code, or a fiddle that reproduces your issue...

Comment: based on the snapshot, the selector should be `$("#section_screen_mobilelistview_9_0 ui-li-count").text("new value");`

Answer (score 0):

add a `.` (dot) in the find filter for both the classes, and leave no spaces between them:

```
$('li[name=mobilelistitem_9]').find(".ui-li-count.ui-body-b").text())
```

you are searching for a `class`, that's why you need the dot. No white space = "both classes"

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/z2zJL/1/

I stole the fiddle from **ezanker** comment, and modified it a bit: as you can see only the 2nd list item will return a result.